# boost serialization stringstream error

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

So...

Whenever I run the following:

```
#inlcude <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

using namespace std;

class gps_position
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & degrees;
        ar & minutes;
        ar & seconds;
    }
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;
public:
    gps_position(){};
    gps_position(int d, int m, float s) :
        degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s)
    {}
};

int main() {
    stringstream ss1;

    const gps_position g(35, 59, 24.567f);

    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss1);
        oa << g;
    }

    gps_position newg;
    {
        stringstream ss2;
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss2);
        ia >> newg;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
   what():   output stream error
Aborted
```

So... This baffles me... any help would be GREAT!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `main` you populate `ss1`, then create a new `std::stringstream` called `ss2` and try to read from that. How would you expect this to work? It's clear that `ss2` contains no data.